# How to pass value through props to another component and error : `Use the defaultValue or value props on instead of setting selected on <option>`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to pass the selected value through the `prop`: `handle state change`, but I am getting two errors.

*Error 1 : Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on  instead of setting `selected` on `<option>`*

*Error 2 : cannot read property 'active' of undefined at StateData*

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import { FormControl , makeStyles, InputLabel,Select} from '@material-ui/core';
import {options} from '../../api/api'


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));


const ComboBox = ({handleStateChange}) =>{
  const styles = useStyles();

  const [fetchedStates,setFetchedStates] = useState([]);
  const [ value , setValue] = useState('')
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchAPI = async() => {
            setFetchedStates(await options());
        }
        fetchAPI()
    },[setFetchedStates]);


  const inputEvent = (e) =>{
  console.log(e.target.value)
  setValue(e.target.value)
  handleStateChange(e.target.value)
}

    return (
    <div>
    <FormControl variant="outlined" className={styles.formControl}>
        <InputLabel>States</InputLabel>
        <Select
          defaultValue=''
          value={value}
          onChange={inputEvent}
          label="States"
        >
        {fetchedStates.map((states, i) => <option key={i} value={states}>{states}</option>)}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default  ComboBox
```

```
//***This is where the API call happens***//

var url = 'https://api.covid19india.org/data.json';

 export const StateData = async(states) =>{
  let stateName = 'Nagaland'
  if(states){
    stateName = {states}
  }
  const response =await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const pop = data.statewise;
  const index = pop.findIndex(st => st.state === stateName)
  const statedta = {
      active :pop[index].active,
      confirmed : pop[index].confirmed,
      deaths : pop[index].deaths,
      recovered: pop[index].recovered
    }
    return statedta
}



export async function ChartData() {

    try{
        let response = await fetch(`https://api.covid19india.org/data.json`);
        return await response.json()
        .then(data=>{
            const pop = data.cases_time_series
            const modifiedData = pop.map((totalData)=>({
                confirmed : totalData.totalconfirmed,
                deaths : totalData.totaldeceased,
                recovered : totalData.totalrecovered,
                date : totalData.date
            }))
            return modifiedData;
        });
      }catch(err){
        console.error(err);
}
}

export async function options() {
  const response =await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const pop = data.statewise.map(st=>st.state);
  return pop
}
```

Comment: can you share your API response?

Comment: @Harshkurra  which API response you want?.The repoonse for each state( this response is for nagaland) : {active: "189", confirmed: "330", deaths: "0", recovered: "141"}

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few fixes.

1. Use [NativeSelect](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#customized-selects) if you are using your own `options`.
2. There was a bug in `StateData` fun. Don't put `states` in an object.
3. use a separate useEffect to call `StateData`fun.

All your issues are fixed. See [working demo of your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-issue-fix-5jzn9?file=/demo.js)

**jsx snippet**

```js
export default function ComboBox({ handleStateChange }) {
  const [fetchedStates, setFetchedStates] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [individualStateDetails, setIndividualStateDetails] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setFetchedStates(await options());
    };
    fetchAPI();
  }, [setFetchedStates]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetchedStates.length) {
      StateData(value).then(data => {
        setIndividualStateDetails(data);
      });
    }
  }, [value]);

  const inputEvent = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setValue(e.target.value);
    handleStateChange(e.target.value);
  };
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="outlined">
        <InputLabel>States</InputLabel>
        <NativeSelect
          defaultValue=""
          // value={value}
          onChange={inputEvent}
          label="States"
        >
          {fetchedStates.map((states, i) => (
            <option key={states + i} value={states}>
              {states}
            </option>
          ))}
        </NativeSelect>
      </FormControl>
      <div>
        {individualStateDetails &&
          JSON.stringify(individualStateDetails, null, 2)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have a problem, I had made the `Comobox` a different JSX file, so I want whatever option the user chooses it should pass the data to different JSX file and show the data, **so my question is how I can pass the data to a different JSX file?**